# Installed Ubuntu on my laptop but can't boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi

I have a Toshiba laptop which has pre-installed Windows 10 on a UEFI partition. It refused to boot few days ago with a `no bootable device` error so I turned to my Ubuntu (20.04) usb stick which I had tried out before. I checked my hard drive for errors on Ubuntu. SMART was ok, bad sector search with fdisk also didn't have anything to report. So I assume the hard disk is ok.

I don't know what went wrong but I decided to get rid of Windows and use Ubuntu hoping it can solve the issue. Installed Ubuntu from the stick via the shortcut on the desktop. Installation done and it asked me to restart. I removed the stick, gave it a restart and got the same `no bootable device` error. I had chosen to remove everything on the hard drive before the install but I think it couldn't get rid of that UEFI part so the computer still trying to boot on that corrupted partition. So I am still using Ubuntu on usb stick and have to reconfigure everything at each time. Awaiting your expert views on this matter. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have Secure Boot enabled, and did you install Ubuntu in [EFI mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)? My guess is that the GRUB installation failed even though it says otherwise during the Ubuntu installation process.

Comment: Actually I don't know in which mode I installed Ubuntu in because I was turning on and off secure boot and uefi boot options in bios to solve the issue so I don't remember their last state when I installed Ubuntu.

Comment: If your laptop comes with UEFI, Ubuntu has to be installed in EFI mode. Ubuntu 20.04 can handle Secure Boot properly even when it is enabled. Sometimes it's Windows that is locking the bootloader from being changed through fast startup. https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

Comment: Also, boot-repair might help you so you don't have to re-install Ubuntu. I think it can also restore the Windows boot loader (if the files are still in the EFI partition) so you can boot to Windows again. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Ok, installed boot-repair and tried quick fix option. It tells me `The current session is in BIOS-compatibility mode. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB) that is compatible with UEFI booting mode. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode. This will enable this feature.`

Comment: Yes, try as the boot-repair suggested. Disable Legacy or CSM mode in your UEFI BIOS. One thing to notice is that in EFI mode, the GRUB dialog that pops up from the Ubuntu installer will be in black and white instead of purple and white. Good luck!

Comment: I have enabled secure boot on and UEFI in BIOS now and a black and white menu came up with options to launch Ubuntu and other two options. When I chose Ubuntu it just restarts and came back to same menu and on few tries I got the same `no bootable device` error. I think Ubuntu cannot load because I installed in legacy mode. Should I install it again now? I log on with USB stick again.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. A possible explanation is that Secure Boot database in your laptop does not have Canonical's keys installed, such that Secure Boot won't permit booting Ubuntu in EFI mode. If that's the case, disabling Secure Boot should allow you to boot Ubuntu installer in EFI mode. Once you get in, try boot-repair again. Hopefully if boot-repair is able to repair your bootloader, you won't need to re-install Ubuntu.

Comment: I kept trying last night and re-installed Ubuntu after deleting all the partitions and creating a new EFI and Ext4 partition but it didn't work. I was not going to create EFI partition but I got a warning that it should cause problems if I don't. Anyway it didn't work as pc got frozen even before loading anything. I'll try boot-repair again but doing some bad sector scans now.

Comment: "sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda > bad-blocks-result
Checking blocks 0 to 488386583
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done                                                 
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)"

Comment: I ran boot repair. It said something like the repair was successfull but nothing changed. Its frozen right after the start. Btw I'm getting some I/O errors while logging on from Ubuntu usb stick which wasn't happening few days ago. Looks like hard drive has a problem other than bad sectors.

Comment: I have deleted all the partitions. Disabled secure boot and enabled csm on bios. Then installed Ubuntu and I got this error saying attempt to read or write outside of disk ‘hd0’. Entering rescue mode... grub rescue>

Comment: Hmm, something is fishy here. Can you boot with the installer and paste the output of the following terminal command: `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` (that's a lowercase "L" for "list")

Comment: GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************

Disk /dev/sda: 976773168 sectors, 465.8 GiB
Model: HGST HTS545050A7
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 3C332815-8297-417B-B219-6462439174AE
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
...

Comment: Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 976773134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 6125 sectors (3.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1050623   512.0 MiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   5         1052672       976771071   465.3 GiB   8300  Linux filesystem

Comment: Btw, problem solved last night. I don't know how but it has somehow solved. I'm running ubuntu from hard drive now.

Comment: My guess is that the `gdisk` command somehow fixed the misaligned partition table. Glad to help!

Comment: I don't know if you were joking but has it really fixed something?

Comment: Well, it's either that, or the last Ubuntu re-installation. I'm not sure which (:.

Comment: Actually I was able to boot before the gdisk command you suggested but after running this command I got the Grub menu with all the options. Before, I had no Grub menu at all. It was loading the OS directly. It took so long to get to logon screen though. I think this hard drive has some physical problem. Thanks a lot for all your help.